# Azure Functions deployment source Visual Studio Team Service project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am trying to link the Azure Functions deployment to integrate with Visual Studio Team Service however once I select VSTS as the source, it doesn't show any other projects.

I have other web apps in my account which feed from a VSTS project.

The reason this is important to us is because of the workflow. We currently use AWS API Gateway + Lambda for our webhooks however it doesn't fit our development/deployment workflow.

Comment: It's likely not related to functions. See if this helps: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Setting-up-a-VSTS-account-so-it-can-deploy-to-a-Web-App.

Comment: The account is a linked AAD account and we have other web apps that source from other projects in the same account (in the same Azure resource group/region/subscription).

Comment: I agree it's likely not related to functions but I wonder what I am missing.

Comment: What if you try to link a new (non-function) Web App? The UI to pick VSTS project should really be agnostic of the app type.

Comment: What's version control system for other projects? TFVC or Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select "Visual Studio Team Services" as deployment source from New Azure Portal, it is using [Kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) which is designed for Git version control. So it will only show the projects with "Git" repositories.

> Kudu is the engine behind git deployments in Azure Web Sites. It can
>   also run outside of Azure.

If you want to deploy the TFVC project, try with [Azure Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/). You can refer to this article for details: [Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Team Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/)

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Created a Git project and it shows up the list. Thanks!