# Cannot set deployment from source control for Azure App Service

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Am trying to setup deployment from source control for Azure App Service. Am facing errors in the same. The error that am receiving is:

```
Cannot create build definition as no hosted build controller could be found.
```

Am trying to configure this via "Visual Studio Online" option by clicking "Setup deployment from source control" in a slot of Azure App Service.
[image: Error on classic portal]

[image: Error on New Portal]

Comment: Can you share detailed steps?

Comment: 1. Created a TFS Online Project.
2. Created Azure App Service.
3. Checked-in code for the first time of the application that is running locally successfully.
4. Created slot (apidev) for App Service.
5. Tried to configure TFS Project as Deployment source for apidev slot of App Service.
6. Got the above error for new portal.

For old portal,
1st 4 steps same as above.
5. Tried to configure "Setup deployment from source control" in a slot of Azure App Service
6. Got the above error for old portal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your question:

For the New Portal, it can only show the projects with Git Version Control. If you project is using Team Foundation Version Control(TFVC), it cannot be listed. You can refer to this question for deteails: [Azure Functions deployment source Visual Studio Team Service project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454599/azure-functions-deployment-source-visual-studio-team-service-project).

For the Classic Portal, I can get the same issue with you and it is caused by the failure when create a XAML build definition. When you create a XAML build definition from VS directly, you should get a similar error message:

[image]

I have help you submit a feedback on Microsoft Connect Page, you can track the detailed information here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2699963

**Update:**
According to the information in Microsoft Connect Page, there is no Hosted Build Controller for new VSTS account. So you need to setup your own on-premise build controller to fix the issue for Classic Portal.