# Azure - Error while connecting to VSTS from Deployment Source

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to implement Continuous Integration using Azure App Service and VSTS.

When I drill down into "Deployment Source" and then select "Visual Studio Team Services" and then "Choose a Project", it doesn't display any projects. The project panel says "no results". I'm currently signed into both Azure portal and VSTS using the same account.

I also could not see anything related to Azure in my Security and Policy --> "Apps and Services" section of my account in https://account.live.com.

Thanks in Advance.
Prawin

Comment: What's the version control system of your VSTS project? Git or TFVC? And are you using the new azure portal?

Comment: @Prawin did you resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because your Team Services and Azure accounts aren't linked (was for me anyway).

Bound to change in future, but here's how to link them now:

From the Azure portal home page, click "Browse", then "Team Services Accounts (preview)", then link them together.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new azure portal and select "Deployment Source", only the projects with "Git" repository will be listed. Refer to this question for details:
[Azure Functions deployment source Visual Studio Team Service project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454599/azure-functions-deployment-source-visual-studio-team-service-project)

Comment: Same problem. My project is Git and I'm using the new portal but it's still saying "No results".